# How does processmaker engine work?

Tags: workflow, business-process-management, business-process, processmaker

After I finish the design of the process in the bpmn notation..processmaker transform the bpmn to xpdl to execute this process? or use bpel?

Answer (score 2):

I've used ProcessMaker for 3 years, and it seems to me it doesn't use BPEL.

Check this: http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/ProcessMaker_Architecture_Diagrams

It doesn't mention anything about it BPEL or XPDL.

To execute the process, ProcessMaker generates code files and XML files, which contain the business logic you designed before using DynaForms.

So, it's not just designing the process using BPMN notation, you have to build data entry forms, derivation rules, create user groups, give them permission and even some custom programming.

This is not "magic".

Answer (score 0):

The current version of ProcessMaker 2.5.0 is not BPMN or BPEL compliant. But the Roadmap of the product includes the BPMN compliant implementation (http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/ProcessMaker_RoadMap).
Currently the engine uses tasks, events, steps, dynaforms, input and output documents and triggers to execute processes.

Answer (score 0):

Current version of processmaker has not a BPEL or BPMN engine. But processmaker can execute processes because have an engine. To execute a case you need to go to the inbox tab and start a new case, of course you need to configure user access at the designing time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about XPDEL or BPEL but based on my experience, processmaker will store everything on their workspace database, that's why they use PMT_ prefixes if you create report table, for separate user created table and processmaker system tables. If you create case, processmaker will create CASE in table APP_DELEGATION with process, task, application (cases), user and anything related to your CASE.
So basically they will serve form based on APP_DELEGATION data, this table also stored every steps of CASES. If your submit your form, they will make a new row in APP_DELEGATION with sampe process and application but new TASK (TAS_UID) related to designer path(arrow on your screen).

Basically they just store information, serve it based on information, and route it based on your design. Even your uploaded file will be noted on processmaker databases system (they will create UID and other important information, even the uploader user information). And not compiling or translate it to another language. Simple but not so simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

ProcessMaker's latest version (released in January 2020) - ProcessMaker 4.x- is fully BPMN 2.0 compliant.  You can important and export BPMN 2.0 files from other BPMN 2.0 compliant designers into ProcessMaker.

BPEL is really no longer used by anyone in the industry.  It lost support a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

In summary, ProcessMaker 4 requirements for a server can be seen at this [link.](https://processmaker.gitbook.io/processmaker/install-processmaker/prerequisites#on-premises-server-requirements)

ProcessMaker still uses the stack for installation: apache or nginx, mysql database and php language. Aditionally, Lavaravel framework is used in ProcessMaker. ProcessMaker as a bmnp software needs complies with the BPMN 2.0 standards.